# Streaming mp4 files to another websites

Tags: video, server, streaming, red5, plex

I have more than 10.000 funny videos. All files mp4 and these files a quite big.

I am not interested in live streaming or compatible with devices like Ipad, Iphone, Android... etc. I am trying to stream these videos to another websites.

So, what should I do and what the best way to stream videos ?

Plex is home theater, Red5 is a quite difficult.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you say "I am not interested in streaming" so you would probably look at something which is called progressive download (also called "pseudo streaming").

You can imagine this like a fancy download:

- You can watch while streaming
- You can seek/jump in the video forward and backward

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_download

You usually require an additional mod or plugin on a WebServer to support seeking.

Wikipedia actually lists some plugins for popular web servers that support it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_download#Seeking

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. "pseudo streaming" is what I look for. I may edit the question or I should post a new one about it.

Comment: I feel [http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430518-pseudo-streaming-in-flash] and [http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/pseudostreaming.html] players offer NginX but G-wan is faster. 
G-wan benchmarks page : [http://gwan.com/benchmark]


Can anyone help me to choose a server between Apache, NginX and G-wan  or better server for "pseudo streaming"  ?

Comment: I the past people tend to use lighttpd for pseudo streaming. A common practise is also to use Apache HTTPD and then have some mod_proxy or similar installed to forward some traffic to lighttpd or nginx. Nginx performs a bit better under some circumstances.